# AngularJS & UI Bootstrap(DatePicker) - After date selection, the ngModel will not keep the UTC timestamp

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using:

- UI Bootstrap datePicker component (ver. 0.13.4)
- AngularJS (ver 1.4.5)

I'm trying to format the binded ngModel value of the user selected date, so I can pass the value as a UTC timestap via $http

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">

    <p>Selected date is: {{ formData.dt | date:'fullDate' }}</p>
    <p>The binded ngModel is: {{ formData.dt }}</p>

    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
        <datepicker 
            ng-model="formData.dt"
            min-date="minDate"
            max-date="maxDate" 
            show-weeks="false"
            starting-day = "1"
            class="">
        </datepicker>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

here is the Controller

```
var app = angular.module('formApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

app.controller('formController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.formData = {};

  var date = new Date();
  $scope.formData.dt = date.getTime();

});
```

and here is a Plunker demo - http://plnkr.co/edit/3vKIO3187ZC2FAnlw2ZW?p=preview

As you will see, selecting any date in the picker changes the model format.
How can I set it so when any date is selected, it still has a UTC value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own `$parser` inside a directive to format the date value how you want it to be formatted.

```
app.directive('dateAsMs', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
        if (value && value.getTime) {
          return value.getTime();
        } else {
          return value;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And then add the attribute `date-as-ms` to your `datepicker` element

Here is your modified plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0V3CkLt8Gjtwc9Jj3zxE?p=preview